# Is there a timeout on a BinaryReader ReadByte()?

Tags: .net, tcp

I have inherited some code that is looping through a response from a BinaryReader, and it is working fine (returning 2 bytes) for a while, but then the client takes a while to respond (I am supposing) and the code falls into the catch logic.

I can't find any documentation as to how long the ReadByte() will wait, it appears to wait for roughly 3 seconds, and then fail.

Does anyone know exactly how the ReadByte works?  Can I configure it to somehow wait a little longer?  My code is below, thanks.

```
public virtual Byte[] Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 recSize) {
    Byte[] rbuffer = new Byte[recSize];

    var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);

    Int32 index = 0;
    try {
        binaryWriter.Write(buffer);

        do {
            rbuffer[index] = binaryReader.ReadByte(); // Read 1 byte from the stream
            index++;
        } while (index < recSize);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Error(ex);
        return rbuffer;
    }
    return rbuffer;
}
```

PS - recSize in the code is 2, it is always expecting 2 bytes to return.

Comment: Can you include the function definition for this method and the details of the exception that is thrown when it does fail.

Comment: Sure @ScottChamberlain, I've just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinaryReader` itself has no timeout, it is just a wrapper for the underlying stream. The thing that is timing out is whatever stream you passed in as `stream`. You must modify that object's timeout (or it's parents if that stream is just another wrapper too).

You don't need to use BinaryReader at all to do what you want to do, also assuming that `buffer` is a `byte[]` you don't need BinaryWriter either.

```
Byte[] rbuffer = new Byte[recSize];

try {
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    Int32 index = 0;
    do
    {
        index += stream.Read(rbuffer, index, rbuffer.Length - index);
    } while (index < recSize);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.Error(ex);
    return rbuffer; //I would either let the exception bubble up or return null here, that way you can tell the diffrence between a exception and an array full of 0's being read.
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok Scott, I looked at the code and it appears to be a global variable that is set earlier on.  It's definition is: protected internal System.IO.Stream stream = null;

Comment: @MarkKadlec somewhere later in the code there will be a `stream = new Somthing(...)` that is where it is being set. Seeing your update it looks like it is some kind of `NetworkStream`, you will need to find where it is created and change the timeout.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that was exactly it.  Sadly that doesn't fix my problem (I think it's on the client end), but now I can easily toggle the readTimeout.